# VS 2017 Pull operation failed

Tags: git, visual-studio

I went to do a `sync` in VS 2017 (15.3.5) Team explorer and it says `pull` operation failed. I am using `git` as version control.

This is the error I got:

```
Remote: Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Services        
Remote: 
Remote: Found 18 objects to send. (631 ms)        
Pull operation failed.*
```

I've tried several things:

1. Delete the branch and checkout again.
2. Connect to team system again.

Nothing works. expecting expert advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below steps worked.

1. `git fetch -p`
2. deleting the local branch and check out it again.

But make sure you don't have any commits to sync.

3. Worst case you can delete the local repository and clone again.

red below articles as well. this might be useful.

[More info 1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/122161/pull-operation-failed.html)

[More Info 2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19225/error-pull-operation-failed-when-pulling.html)

Comment: So, I was having these issues: 
While fetching: Error encountered while fetching: FetchCommand.ExecuteFetch
Pull: Pull operation failed on a specific branch
Sync wasn't working either (wasn't opening the output window).
I ran this command (git fetch -p) and it fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are various reasons this can happen. I've been frustrated a few times when the only feedback I could see was "Pull operation failed." Here are a couple of steps that have helped me...

- If you have any local changes, try performing a *Commit All* from the *Changes* section of VS Team Explorer. Then try to *Pull* again. If you're able to do this, then chances are there are conflicts you'll have to resolve, but VS/Git should allow you to resolve them at this point.
- If that doesn't work, go to the *Sync* section of VS Team Explorer and try doing a *Fetch.* Hopefully the you see a list of the changes you need to get pulled to your machine. If so, right-click the oldest one and select *Cherry-Pick.* When you do this, VS/Git will show you any problems (at the top of the *Synchronization* tab) with the specific pull. If no issues are listed, then try selecting/cherry-picking the next set of changes you need to pull, and continue this until, hopefully, you find some info that helps you start digging into the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened when I changed the http proxy from the corporate proxy to an external site proxy. I forgot to switch it back, and so it failed. Switched back to the corporate proxy and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved just launching the prune command on the git bash

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue probably was that some other process kept files and prevented the pull operation. I just run the command as an administrator and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Creating new branch and merging from origin/master (actual) branch worked for me